# What is the correct way to recognize whether a user is using the app?

Tags: android

I want to use notifications in the notification bar when the user is outside the app, and toast notifications when they are using it.

The notifications (either style) will be issued from a Service so there will be no knowledge of any activities at the time of notifying.

What is the correct and most reliable pattern to make sure you know this?

Comment: Using GCM? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819663/check-if-app-is-open-during-a-gcm-onmessage-event/15949194#15949194

Comment: That has nothing to do with GCM - figuring out how to display a GCM message was simply the motivation in that case.  But the general idea - activities know if they are in the foreground, have each candidate inform the service, holds.

Comment: You guessed correctly. It was in conjunction with GCM. Thanks I think this will work, but the answer passes the activity instance over. I don't think this is necessary. Just a simple boolean will be enough.

Comment: This might be useful, depending on your situation: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on Klaasvaak's suggestion from another question here's what I did (but it's a bit simpler than the suggested)

In my service (or in any other class. Probably better to be in a more universal class) we have this code...

```
...
private static boolean viewingApp = false;

public static synchronized void setViewingApp(boolean viewing)
{
    viewingApp = viewing;
}

public static boolean isViewingApp()
{
    return viewingApp;
}
...
```

If the above class gets destroyed it will be fine, because the boolean will revert back to false if needed again.

The setViewingApp() method above gets executed in a base class which every Activity extends...

```
...
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    MyClassCOntainingTheBoolean.setViewingApp(true);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    MyClassCOntainingTheBoolean.setInApp(false);
    super.onPause();
}
...
```