# How to Stop GCM When app is Running

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i Want to stop GCM Notification When app is running

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());


    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
```

i tried to get the context Value but there is no difference when app is Running or not

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819663/check-if-app-is-open-during-a-gcm-onmessage-event

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just ignore the GCM event in your GCMIntent service when the App is in the foreground.

The event will still come into your service, you just won't perform your action when the app is running.

So, in your GCMIntent service, the pseudo-code would look like:

```
protected void onReceive(Context cxt, Intent arg1) {
if (!APP_IS_RUNNING) {
    // Do your GCM related action
}
...
```

As an alternative, you could also de-register your device from GCM when the app is running, so the messages are no longer sent, but I think this would be trickier (and you would have to remember to re-register on app close, which can be challenging).

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that you can use which is

> GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister

it will stop messages from arriving to your app until you register to GCM again.
but it's not recommended by google devs