# Gmail like notification functionality android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to implement notification functionality like GMAIL i.e. if the screen is currently opened, the list should auto refresh and no notification is received. If the app is closed then we receive notification. In GMAIL if we are at Inbox and new mail arrives, its automatically appended at top without notification and if app isn't opened we get notification for new mail.
I have coded the notification part and its working fine but only thing is even if I am in current activity, I still get notifications which I am trying to stop.

Below is the code from Intent class to send notification

```
Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ListActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(listIntent);

PendingIntent listPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("xxxx")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("Update List"))
                .setContentText("Update List").setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setContentIntent(listPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

I researched a lot on web & SO but didn't get any relevant pointers. There seems to be a solution from CommonsWare but I do not want to use any external library. Also during my research I found that knowing which activity is on top isn't a good practice to do in production so can't use that too to stop notification is my current activity is on top. Please advise.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15949723/321354

Comment: `knowing which activity is on top isn't a good practice to do in production` why? is there any problem?

Comment: don't show the notification if your present activity is open... That one solved your issue.

Comment: @rciovati Thanks for the suggestion. I will try and let you know if any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one solved your issue

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            boolean isActivityFound = false;

            if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName().toString()))
            {
                isActivityFound = true;
            }
            if (!isActivityFound)
            {
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("xxxx")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("Update List"))
            .setContentText("Update List").setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    builder.setContentIntent(listPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
            }
```